# How to mock required module function with Jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following code which I need to test:

**createCassandraDriver**

```
const driver = require('cassandra-driver')
module.exports = ({
  cassandra_user,
  cassandra_password,
  cassandra_address
}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const client = new driver.Client({
        contactPoints: cassandra_address.split(','),
        authProvider: authProvider(cassandra_user, cassandra_password),
        queryconfig: {
          consistency: driver.types.consistencies.quorum
        }
      })
      return resolve(client)
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}
```

I'm trying to mock the call to 'driver.Client'.
I tried doing it using 'spyOn', like so:

```
'use strict';
const rewire = require('rewire'),
      driver = require('cassandra-driver'),
      createCassandraDriver = require('../../lib/createCassandraDriver.js');

const defaultArguments = () => {
  return {
    'cassandra_address': '127.0.0.1',
    'cassandra_user': 'cassandra_user',
    'cassandra_password': 'cassandra_password'
  };
}

jest.mock("cassandra-driver");

describe('Create cassandra driver tests', function () {
  describe('success flow', function () {
    it('Should pass without any errors ', async function () {    
        await createCassandraDriver(defaultArguments())
    });
  });
  afterEach(function () {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
  });
});
```

****mocks** file**

```
const driver = jest.genMockFromModule('cassandra-driver');
driver.Client = function () {return "cassandra_client"}    
module.exports = driver;
```

But I get an error message that says 'driver is not a function' which is true.

How I can mock the call to 'driver.Client' then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [Manual Mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) to mock external dependencies in your Jest tests.

---

1. Create a directory called `__mocks__` next to `node_modules`.
2. Create file `__mocks__/cassandra-driver.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  types: {
    consistencies: {
      quorum: null
    }
  },
  Client: jest.fn()
};
```

3. Add following line to your test file:

```
jest.mock("cassandra-driver");
```

---

Now every time you import `cassandra-driver` in your test, or in any files imported in your test, the module which you implemented in step 2 will be imported instead.

This allows you to call driver.Client with any of the [mock methods](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html) to replace implementation, stub return value, or access mock instances.

Here's a complete test example:

```
import driver from "cassandra-driver";
import createCassandraDriver from "./createCassandraDriver";

jest.mock("cassandra-driver");

const clientStub = {
  foo: "bar"
};

driver.Client.mockImplementation(() => clientStub);

it("renders without crashing", async () => {
  const result = await createCassandraDriver({
    cassandra_user: "foo",
    cassandra_password: "bar",
    cassandra_address: "baz"
  });

  expect(result).toEqual(clientStub);
});
```

Comment: I just found the documentation about it, and followed your suggestion, but still its using the actual module.
Updated my question with current test code.

Comment: Where does the error "driver is not a function" come from?

Comment: No error, it just acts normally, as if no mock is used.

Comment: I've updated the question is the mock file and current test file. With the current mock file it does not return a 'real' driver as before, but a contractor.

Comment: So it no longer uses the real driver, is my understanding correct? What behavior are trying to achieve and how is it failing?

Comment: You are correct, the behavior I wish for is that the constractor will return a JSON object or that the call to the constractor will throw an error.

Comment: Where you have `return "cassandra_client"` you can have `return {/* your json */}`, but I assume you want to configure this on per test basis. Then you should replace `function () {return "cassandra_client"}` with `jest.fn()` and use `driver.Client.mockImplementation` as shown in the example above.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. One last question, can I spy on the calls made to 'driver.Client' ?

Comment: Yes, you can access recent calls in `driver.Client.mock.calls` or simply use `expect(driver.Client).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `jest.spyOn` to spy on the method of an object - here, `driver` is a private variable within the `createCassandraDriver` module so we can't use that.

Looks like you're using the [rewire package](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) from your use of `__set__`? If so, I think you should be able to achieve what you want by using `jest.fn`:

```
let createCassandraDriverSpy = jest.fn(clientMock);
createCassandraDriver.__set__('driver', createCassandraDriverSpy)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not work. I've update the question with the way I build 'clientMock'.

Comment: ah okay have you tried `createCassandraDriver.__set__('driver', clientMock)` ? Btw I think `driverMock` would be a better name for `clientMock`

Comment: Tried to set 'driverMock' still it uses the same function. Perhaps it's related to to fact the the module only contains a function that loads only when I call it?

Comment: what error are you getting now? also could you please update the question to show how you're testing the `createCassandraDriver` module?

Comment: I've updated the question, I don't get any error, when I call createCassandraDriver() function, it just uses the regular 'cassandra-driver' package.

Comment: just seen your updated question - have you tried removing the `let createCassandraDriverSpy ... ` line and changing the next one to `createCassandraDriver.__set__('driver', driverMock)` ?

Comment: Yes, no difference, is my implementation of 'driverMock' good?